# iOS - AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest source image is empty

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avasset, avmutablecomposition

I use [AVMutableVideoComposition(asset:applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmutablevideocomposition/1387006-init) to apply CIFilter for each frame. Here is my code:

```
let mainTrackAsset = AVAsset(url: url)
let mainCompositionWithFilter = AVMutableVideoComposition(asset: mainTrackAsset) { request in                
    let source = request.sourceImage
}
```

It works fine with video recorded from device, but if I save video from for example, Google Drive, `source` is empty CIImage 
`fill [0 0 0 1 devicergb]
extent=[infinite][0 0 1 1]
opaque`

The only difference between recorded and saved from web videos is that first element of `mainTrackAsset.tracks` has media type `video` for recorded and `audio` for saved from web

Is it a bug in AVFoundation or I've not understood how it works?
Is there possibility to rearrange indices of `mainTrackAsset.tracks`?

Comment: Very strange... Have you tried using `AVURLAsset`? `AVAsset` is an abstract class.

Comment: @FrankSchlegel same problem with `AVURLAsset` too

Comment: Could you please post the description of both assets for comparison?